# Why is the behavior different between this Tensorflow and PyTorch LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have a very simple Pytorch LSTM I was trying to run on a finance dataset. I have used the form of it before and it has not let me down until now.

The LSTM in PyTorch looks like this

```
class LSTMPredictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=n_features,
            hidden_size=n_hidden,
            batch_first=True,
            num_layers=n_layers,
        )
        self.regressor = nn.Linear(n_hidden, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(x)
        preds = self.regressor(hidden[-1])
        return preds
```

I have trimmed it down to the smallest possible form for which I have the problem.

For the params I have

```
n_features = 19
n_hidden = 256
n_layers = 1
SEQ_LEN=120
```

*In both the torch and tf model these are the params used*

**Now here is my problem**

When I attempt to train this model it does not learn, the loss remains high and fluctuates around +/-50% of what it was originally.

In my attempts to debug the model I eventually tried a Tensorflow (Keras) implementation (couldn't hurt right).

Super simple

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(SEQ_LEN, 19)))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The weird thing is that this model DOES LEARN!?
The loss decreases consistently with each passing step up to a point.

**Some additional info**

- Running on Windows
- torch==2.0.1
- tensorflow==2.14.0
- tf model running on CPU (no Windows support) and torch on GPU
- using AdamW optimizer with constant lr=1e-3 for both (keras.optimizers.AdamW and torch.optim.AdamW resp.)
- both use l1_loss

I have tried running the torch model on CPU, it is not the problem.
I have tried running the same Keras model with the torch backend `import keras_core as keras` with `os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "torch"` and using torch tensors for everything. When I do this the model works.

I am really at a loss right now, how are these two implementations different?
Would really appreciate any help :)

**Edit**
I removed the dropout layers - they have no effect.

**Think I found something**
I think I may have isolated the problem as something to do with the difference between torch.float32 and float64. When I run the keras model on the torch backend with float32 the same thing happens where it does not learn, is something happening with vanishing gradients maybe?

Comment: This is not the proper way to use dropouts in Pytorch LSTM. It is `torch.nn.LSTM(dropout = 0.2)` https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html

Answer (score 0):

Your forward method is wrong, you are using `hidden` as your input not `x`!, and you are not using pytorch standard way of LSTM dropout. this is the correct form:

```
class LSTMPredictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden, n_layers, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=n_features,
            hidden_size=n_hidden,
            batch_first=True,
            num_layers=n_layers,
            dropout=dropout_rate # Apply dropout only if there are multiple LSTM layers
        )
        self.regressor = nn.Linear(n_hidden, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        out, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(x)
        preds = self.regressor(hidden[-1])
        return preds
```

P.S. Apply dropout only if there are multiple LSTM layers.

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo. This is not the problem I am facing - after all the model would not run if this were the case.